# A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I receive this error when executing this code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(UserModel user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ja");
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                    var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);
                    UserModel newUser = new UserModel(user.Email, encrpPass);
                    newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

                    userRepository.Add(newUser);
                    userRepository.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {

                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }


            return View(user);
        }
```

UserModel class:

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public int UserModelId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(150)]
        [Display(Name="Email address: ")]
        public String Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "Password: ")]
        public String Password { get; set; }
        public String PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        public UserModel(String email, String password)
        {
            this.Email = email;
            this.Password = password;
        }

        public UserModel()
        {
        }
    }
```

More details on the exception:

> Message "OriginalValues cannot be used for entities in the Added
>   state."   string

Stacktrace:

> StackTrace    "   bij
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   bij
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n
>   bij System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   bij
>   SoccerManager1.Models.DAL.UserRepository.SaveChanges() in
>   d:\Stijn\Documenten\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SoccerManager1\SoccerManager1\Models\DAL\UserRepository.cs:regel
>   48\r\n   bij
>   SoccerManager1.Controllers.UserController.Registration(UserModel user)
>   in d:\Stijn\Documenten\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SoccerManager1\SoccerManager1\Controllers\UserController.cs:regel
>   72"   string

I'm just trying to create a registration page, I don't get it why that I receive this error.

What am I doing wrong here? If this is not enough info that I provided please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422057/originalvalues-cannot-be-used-for-entities-in-the-added-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation may have failed for one of your property values. Might be password for which you have set 'StringLength' to 20 and you are inserting encrypted password. Or might be not passing value for some not null fields.

For debugging and finding actual cause you may use following code block in your catch :

```
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} throws Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was indeed the password, however I get that it was beyond the 20 limit, I was just following example code from YouTube lol, he didn't get any errors. Doesn't really matter, thanks!